# Vue Router Match issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using https://github.com/posva/unplugin-vue-router#readme to create routes. (By vitesse template)

My folder structure creates this:
https://paths.esm.dev/?p=AAMeJaCAuCDAEAg2AAUF6EpAnGgRcPaAuALjAgC4CVhNYcDgnB3YAmcKD3X4PpmGgE0KJ5QAiAIQBCACXBYgZAAA&t=/hi/asd/other#

The /hi/asd and /hi/asd/other matches the view for /hi/:name, based on the view content in that file.

The folder structure I am using:

```
src/pages (folder)
src/pages/hi (folder)
src/pages/hi/[name] (folder)
src/pages/hi/[name]/other.vue
src/pages/hi/[name].vue
src/pages/[...all].vue
src/pages/about.md
src/pages/index.vue
src/pages/README.md
```

Why is it not matching the other.vue?

Answer (score 0):

Routes are matched in order of definition.
The /hi/:name route is defined before the /hi/:name/other route, so it will always be matched first.
**Resolve:**
Just define route /hi/:name/other before route /hi/:name.
I hope this will help.

Comment: With unplugin-vue-router, I don't have direct access for the ordering, but this should work out of the box, because in the options, they order by length

Answer (score 0):

Using `src/pages/hi/[name].other.vue` instead of `src/pages/hi/[name]/other.vue`, it works. I guess this is a bug.